# JavaScript radio button checking related issue

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

After checking a  radio button, when I select another option it still remains checked. I want to uncheck it when I select another option, but it isn't doing so. The code is not working when I use bootstrap css. Where is the bug?

HTML :

```
<select class="form-control job-subcategory" autocomplete="off" name="job_subcategory">
    <option class="sub-catg-options" value="">Select Sub-Category(Optional)</option>
    <option class="electric-subcategory" value="Emergency Electricians">Emergency Electricians</option>
    <option class="electric-subcategory" value="Alarm Installer">Alarm Installer</option>
    <option class="electric-subcategory" value="Electrical Lighting">Electrical Lighting</option>
    <option class="electric-subcategory" value="Back Up Generators">Back Up Generators</option>
</select>
```

Radio 1 (preselected)
    
    
         Radio 2
    
    
         Radio 3

My JS code:

```
$('.job-subcategory').change(function () {
if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Emergency Electricians") {
    $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
}
else if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Alarm Installer") {
    $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
}
else if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Electrical Lighting") {
    $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
}
else if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Back Up Generators") {
    $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you use bootstrap, the DOM needs longer to load than a almost-blank page. So register your `change` event when your doc is ready (see code below). The other thing is, bootstrap adds additional elements outside of your `<select>` element, with own classes. I added the removing on the classes at the end of your `change` event code.

I added the changes in your JS code, it works for me with bootstrap:

```
<!-- If jQuery is not already implemented -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('.job-subcategory').change(function () {
            if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Emergency Electricians") {
                $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
            }
            else if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Alarm Installer") {
                $(':radio').prop('checked', false); 
            }
            else if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Electrical Lighting") {
                $(':radio').prop('checked', false);     
            }
            else if ($('.job-subcategory').val() == "Back Up Generators") {
                $(':radio').prop('checked', false);     
            }

            $('.btn-group').find('label').removeClass('active');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Fabian Picone, This code is working properly.

Comment: @MuktoMona You're welcome! So you can mark my answer as solved :-)

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is with the bootstrap css. Eventhough your js uncheck the radio the css shows it as selected because the `active` class on the `label` is not removed. You have to remove the `active` class from `label`s to make them look like unchecked.

You can try this code from @Fabian Picone's answer:

```
$('.btn-group').find('label').removeClass('active');
```

to remove the active class.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/qqwLgr94/1/